# HTTPRequest got 500 status code rather than 200

Tags: c#, httprequest, restsharp

I am writing a program to retrieve all my Apple account Info, the page is 
https://secure.store.apple.com/shop/account/setup/start

I found that I should post three parameters [accountName], [password], [rememberMe] to https://idmsa.apple.com/appleauth/auth/signin in order to login. However, I got 500 error status. I can access the page through my browser (got 200 status), so what's wrong with me? Thanks.

I am debugging in postman by:

POST: https://idmsa.apple.com/appleauth/auth/signin

Params:

[accountName, MyAppleID]

[password, MyPassword]

[rememberMe, false]

and my C# code: (Using RestSharp)

```
        var restClient = new RestClient();
        restClient.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://idmsa.apple.com/appleauth/auth/signin");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("accountName", MyAppleID);
        request.AddParameter("password", MyPassword);
        request.AddParameter("rememberMe", "false");
        IRestResponse response = restClient.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);     // show "InternalServerError"
```

Comment: What is the code you used? Impossible to guess what you did wrong. You do not even say what language you are using....

Comment: @epascarello I am debugging in postman

Comment: So what is the code? ... (of course do not put actual account values)

Comment: @epascarello I put on my question

Comment: I still see no C# code. Are you sure if question is tagged correctly?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am sorry for that, I am debugging in Postman, and my program written in c#